# How to add translation filter to notification of ngAdmin?

Tags: javascript, ng-admin, angularjs

My code is like this:

```
function enableUser(Restangular, $state, notification) {
    ...
    ...
    notification.log(
        {{ "DISABLED_LOG_DISABLE" | translate }},
        { addnCls: 'humane-flatty-success' });
}
```

I found that it will display `{{ "DISABLED_LOG_DISABLE" | translate }}` directly to the screen but what I need is `Disabled employee` when I give it `{'DISABLED_LOG_DISABLE': 'Disabled employee'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is used in HTML file "{{ "DISABLED_LOG_DISABLE" | translate }"
What you should do is inject $translate and then you call it. For example:

```
$translate('DISABLED_LOG_DISABLE').then(function(translatedString) {...})
```

I guess you are using angular-translate.